# How to generate html form inputs from json?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a Form where I want to be able to edit/change the data. The Data comes from a JSON file and looks like this:

```
data:{
  "contest_id": 26,
  "question":  {
      "title": "what is the capital of germany?",
      "question_id": 27,
      "answers":  [
           {
             "answer_id": 76,
             "answer": "Hamburg",
             "correct" : "false"               
           },
           {
            "answer_id": 77,
            "answer": "Munich",
            "correct" : "false"
           },
           {
             "answer_id": 78,
             "answer": "Berlin",
             "correct" : "true"
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

My basic HTML (from the edit popup) looks like this:

```
// this is just a snippet of the entire form

<input type="radio" id="answerChk_" name="correct">
<input type="text" required></input>
<input type="hidden" id="answer_" value=""></input>
```

So, what I want to achieve is to fetch and inject the answers+answer_id's and if the answer is correct or not -> so that I can post and Update the database.

How is it possible? I dont want to use any plugins...

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Which search terms have you used?

Comment: @vch you're absolutely right, my mistake... wasnt supposed to be there...

Comment: `<input />`'s are self closing...

Comment: Are there always three options for each question? Are you showing one question at a time? or many questions in the same form? Then you need different IDs, as already stated. You can hardcode them, e.g. appending incremental numbers, or dinamically, through jQuery. What is your plan?

Comment: @clapas There can be more than three options so its random. I'm only showing one question at the time and yes, everything should be dynamically...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop trought the array and append the html like this :

```
$.each(data.question.answers, function () {
    $("YourForm").append('<input type="radio" id="answerChk_'+ this.answer_id +'" name="correct" selected="'+this.correct +'">');
    $("YourForm").append('<input type="text" required>'+ this.answer+'</input>');
    $("YourForm").append('<input type="hidden" id="answer_'+ this.answer_id +'" value="'+ this.answer+'"></input>');
});
```

I hope you get the idea.